# Can I refactor my setup of multiple user types using the same table differently/in a more Cake way?

Tags: php, cakephp, orm, cakephp-3.0

I have a `my_users` table and I now need to refactor it by deleting the `role` column in favor of supporting multiple roles per user. So for instance, the 3 user types I'm dealing with are:

1. fighter
2. referee
3. manager

So the table setup looks like this:

**Users.php**

```
use CakeDC\Users\Model\Table\UsersTable as BaseUsersTable;

class UsersTable extends BaseUsersTable
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {   
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->setEntityClass('Users\Model\Entity\User');

        $this->belongsToMany('UserRoles', [
            'through' => 'users_user_roles'
        ]); 

        $this->hasMany('UsersUserRoles', [
            'className' => 'Users.UsersUserRoles',
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
            'saveStrategy' => 'replace',
        ]);
    }

    public function findRole(Query $query, array $options)
    {
        return $query
            ->innerJoinWith('UserRoles', function($q) use ($options) {
                return $q->where(['role_key' => $options['role_key']]);
            });
    }
}
```

**MyUsersTable.php**

```
class MyUsersTable extends Table
{   
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->setTable('my_users');

        $this->setPrimaryKey('user_id');

        $this->belongsTo('Users', [
            'className' => 'Users.Users',
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * @param Cake\Event\Event $event
     * @param Cake\ORM\Query $query
     * @param ArrayObject $options
     */
    public function beforeFind(Event $event, Query $query, \ArrayObject $options)
{
        // set the role
        if (defined(static::class.'::ROLE') && mb_strlen(static::ROLE) > 0) {
            $role = static::ROLE;

            // set user conditions
            $query->innerJoinWith('Users', function($query) use ($role) {
                return $query->find('role', [
                    'role_key' => $role,
                ]);
            });
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param \Cake\ORM\Query $query
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function findByRegistrationCode(Query $query, array $options): Query
    {
        $query->where([
            $this->aliasField('registration_no') => $options['registration_no']
        ]);

        return $query;
    }
}
```

**FightersTable.php**

```
use MyUsers\Model\Table\MyUsers;

class FightersTable extends MyUsersTable
{       
    const ROLE = 'fighter';

    public function initialize(array $config)
    {   
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->setEntityClass('Fighters\Model\Entity\Fighter');
    }       

    /**
     * @param Validator $validator
     * @return Validator $validator
     */
    public function validationDefault(Validator $validator): Validator
    {
        $validator = parent::validationDefault($validator);

        $validator->allowEmpty('field');
    }
}
```

`RefereesTable.php` and `ManagersTable.php` are similar to `FightersTable` but have their own validation rules and may have their own special entity virtual properties and what not.

**Question:** Is there a more cake way of structuring this, or more specifically an alternate way to doing the `beforeFind` to distinguish the role? Had the requirement for `role` stayed 1:1 with users, I might have possibly done something like this:

```
$this->belongsTo('Fighters', [
    'conditions' => [
        'role' => 'fighter'
    ],
    'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
    'className' => 'MyUsers',
]);
```

I'd appreciate any insight into restructuring this.

Comment: I don't see a reason why the user types table objects needs to extend the users table object at all? If it's just validation you can create different sets of validation rules and define which one is used. So Users hasOne FighterProfiles, RefereeProfiless, AdminProfiles + one a set of rules for each should do the job. https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#validation-and-patchentity

Comment: Another reason is so the entities could share similar methods. For instance, if I wanted a virtual _getFullName property I can specify it in `MyUserEntity` and the others will have it. Not to mention any other common method such as searching for an existing 'Organization ID#' which all of them will have and can't be duplicate.

Comment: Use traits, inheritance or behaviors? Or this https://github.com/UseMuffin/Sti Also if every type of user has an org id, just move that id to the users table?

Comment: I'm already using the setup which I specified. Sorry if this was confusing, but I was wondering about questions #1-3, which include if I could avoid the "gotchas". As far as the users table, I wanted to keep it pure if/when someone migrates/updates the schema from CakeDC/users.

Comment: Just copy the users table to an app level migration? I've never been a fan of keeping these kinds of migrations inside a plugin because the users table is very likely to get some extras that the plugin won't cover. You can still add single fields on your app level migration to this table if you don't want to move the whole migration there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define `belongsTo` association to use `findByRole` [finder](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html#belongsto-associations):

```
 $this->belongsTo('Fighters', [
    'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
    'className' => 'MyUsers',
    'finder' => ['byRole' => ['role' => 'fighter']]
]);
```

Of course, you'll have to define the finder in `MyUsers`:

```
public function findByRole(Query $query, \ArrayObject $options)
{
    $role = $options['role'];

    // set user conditions
    $query->innerJoinWith('Users', function($query) use ($role) {
       return $query->find('role', [
          'role_key' => $role,
           ]);
        });
    }
}
```

Also I'd extract `beforeFind` logic into `RoleBehavior` or `MultiRoleBehavior` [behavior](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/behaviors.html), i.e.:
`src/Model/Behavior/RoleBehavior.php`:

```
<?php
namespace App\Model\Behavior;

use Cake\ORM\Behavior;
use Cake\ORM\Query;
use Cake\Event\Event;

/**
 * Role-specific behavior
 */
class RoleBehavior extends Behavior
{

    /**
     * @var array multiple roles support
     */
    protected $_defaultConfig = [
        'roles' => []
    ];


    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);
        if (isset($config['roles'])) {
            $this->config('roles', $config['roles'], false /* override, not merge*/);
        }
    }

    public function beforeFind(Event $event, Query $query, \ArrayObject $options, $primary) {
        // set user conditions
        $query->innerJoinWith('Users', function($query) use ($roles) {
            return $query->find('role', [
                'role_key' => $roles,
            ]);
        });
    }
}
```

It uses multiple roles, but you can simply change it for single role if you need. Here are some other thing to do - probably extract `$query->innerJoinWith('Users'...` into a separate method in the behavior, and call it in `MyUsers::findByRole(...)`...

Next, you can attach this behavior directly to extended classes, just replace static `ROLE` with behavior config:

```
use MyUsers\Model\Table\MyUsers;

class FightersTable extends MyUsersTable
{       
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {   
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->setEntityClass('Fighters\Model\Entity\Fighter');

        $this->addBehavior('Role', [ 'roles' => ['fighter']]);
    }
}
```

Or you can manage your role-specific logic right by attaching behavior to `MyUsers` table (i.e. from a controller):

```
$this->MyUsers->addBehavior('Role', ['roles' => ['manager']])
```

[You also can change the behavior setup on the fly](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/behaviors.html#re-configuring-loaded-behaviors):

```
$this->MyUsers->behaviors()->get('Role')->config([
   'roles' => ['manager'], 
]);
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Awesome answer, just what I was looking for. I primarily split my models into classes because of the flexibility of having separate entities and easier customization for the validation. Do you know if it's possible to define an entity if you have a self-reference association?

Comment: Thanks, glad to help. I don't see it documented, and guess it isn't. I see in doc that entityClass key is used to configure table object, maybe it'll work in reference too. Other solution could be probably to use the same entity, and factory it to needed one. Won't it work for you?

Comment: As you have query in finder, you can call in it $query->map(function($entity) { return $entity->toSpecificEntity(); } );

Comment: Or, probably simpler: $query->map(function($entity) { return new OtherEntity($entity->toArray());})

Comment: Thanks - and totally forgot to click the bounty button :)

Comment: @mederomuraliev it was a good question. It's probably the first time I faced with question on how something could be done in the framework's way (b/c frankly you had already working solution even before asking). I feel like I need to learn on how to ask such kind of question for framework I just started working with... And it's what I plan to learn to do. It was pleasure for me to answering this. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

What I've typically done/seen in a situation where you have multiple roles is use one table to store the roles (let's call it UserRoles), and another lookup table (lets call this UserRoleAssignments) that connects the user to a specific role. So for instance your myUsersTable would contain a hasMany relationship to UserRoleAssignments. This would eliminate the need for the role field as well as the separate tables for each role. Your findRole() method would look something like this:

```
public function findRole(Query $query, array $options)
{
    return $query
        ->innerJoinWith('UserRoleAssignments', function($q) use ($options) {
            return $q->where(['user_id' => $options['user_id']]);
        });
}
```

You could chain a `first()` call to this if you are only expecting that a user will have one role; however, this setup is nice because if a User can have multiple roles than you can simply chain a `toArray()` call and return an array of roles that belong to the user.

Comment: I'm currently already doing something like this, but what about the model setup I have with beforeFind and multiple tables? Is there any alternative?

Comment: I'm not understanding. In the code that you posted you are not doing something like this. If you model your db like I suggested, there is no need to execute a beforeFind() call

Comment: The way I'm creating these users is different, with different required fields for each user and a separate process, thus I split them into separate plugins for each user type to handle the template changes. I'd still need a way to "set" the type of validation process to be used based on the role, so I'd need to define the role on the user at some point. I figured the split models was easier in terms of that and I should've added this to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if I have understood the ideas well, but maybe this code will be helply. It's use something like namespace alias.

FightersTable.php file:

```
namespace App\Model\Table;

use Cake\ORM\Query;
use CakeDC\Users\Model\Table\UsersTable as FighterUsersTable;

class FightersTable extends FighterUsersTable
{
    // Yous callbacks (like beforeFind)
    ...
}
```

Now You have access to CakeDC/Users table:)

Comment: Err - I already had this setup (though my primary Users extends CakeDC Users), I'm just wondering if there's a better way I can restructure what I currently have.